# How can i add labels to the plotted points on google maps in R

Tags: r, google-maps, label

I want to add labels to the points that were plotted on google maps in R. How can i do that?

Here is a subset of my dataframe

```
>dput(data[1:10,])
structure(list(ID = structure(c(24L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 22L, 25L, 
27L, 3L, 7L, 11L), .Label = c("ALB", "ANG", "BBR", "BNF", "BRK", 
"BTG", "CAL", "CAM", "CANV", "CEP", "CHW", "CSS", "DRP", "EAT", 
"FMM", "FRC", "GCB", "GRPR", "HIN", "KFO", "KZR", "LRK", "LSN", 
"MON", "NAP", "OLO", "OLY", "PEO", "POTR", "POW", "SFRG", "WWA", 
"WWW"), class = "factor"), lat = c(48.9434667, 45.775269, 46.442597, 
45.76697, 46.903737, 46.58292, 47.9306472, 44.3772, 44.530811, 
47.4886), lon = c(-114.4125667, -122.558005, -122.907106, -122.514018, 
-123.0178, -122.87845, -123.3565361, -121.6536, -123.145594, 
-117.5786), size = c("tiny", "tiny", "tiny", "tiny", "tiny", 
"tiny", "tiny", "tiny", "tiny", "tiny"), col = c("red", "red", 
"red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"), char = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), .Names = c("ID", "lat", 
"lon", "size", "col", "char"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically i want to add "ID" names beside the labels.

Here is my code

```
data$size <- "tiny"  #create a column indicating size of marker
data$col <- "red"   #create a column indicating color of marker
data$char <- ""   #normal Google Maps pinpoints will be drawn
names(data) <- c("ID", "lat", "lon", "size", "col", "char")  #assign column headings
bb <- qbbox(lat = data[,"lat"], lon = data[,"lon"])
zoom <- min(MaxZoom(latrange=bb$latR,lonrange=bb$lonR))
MyMap <- GetMap.bbox(bb$lonR, bb$latR, MINIMUMSIZE = FALSE, zoom = 5, markers = data, destfile = "MyTile4.png", maptype = "terrain")
```

And finally here is the map that i got from the above code

[image: test map]

Comment: Some data points stay very close to one another. If you label them in a systematic way, I would image some labels would be overlapping. This would make you to arrange labels in a bit more manual way.

Comment: Is there any alternative? I want to know that points correspond to what ID's

Comment: I think no matter what you have to assign lon/lat values for labelling. When you do so, you want to think how you can avoid the overlapping issue. Say you label some points on left side and some others on right side when you see a cluster of data points. This requires you to arrange label lon/lat values.